# Loss in the convolution layer

Tags: tensorflow

So I'm working on image registration to align an image to a template image. I am performing this convolution operation on a Unet output (100x100x100x32) to get a 3D deformation field (100x100x100x3). For clarification, 100x100x100 is the dimension of the image.

```
# transform unet output into a flow field
name = 'vxm_dense'
Conv = getattr(KL, 'Conv%dD' % ndims)
flow_mean = Conv(filters=3, kernel_size=3, padding='same',
                 kernel_initializer=KI.RandomNormal(mean=0.0, stddev=1e-5),
                 name='%s_flow' % name)(unet_model.output)
```

So far everything is clear, but when I run *model.fit()*, I notice in the logs that in addition to the actual *loss*, an additional loss called *vxm_dense_flow_loss* is logged.

```
Epoch 9/60
560/560 [==============================] - 734s 1s/step - loss: 0.0023 - vxm_dense_flow_loss: 0.0216
```

I don't understand,

1. why is this loss calculated?
2. what is the loss function used? I don't have any loss functions (e.g. mse, ncc or mi) configured for it.
3. in order for the loss to be calculated, there must be a ground truth. Which ground truth is used here?

PS: The actual loss is calculated as the mean square error between the registered image and the template image.

Comment: This is impossible to say given the code you provided, the loss/metric must be added somewhere.

Comment: vxm_dense_flow_loss is unknown to Google - would it be right to assume it is defined somewhere in the code you are running?

Comment: This is unanswerable without the full code you are using.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.